# Designing a javascript module, this reference

Tags: javascript

I am learning about javascript modules and how to write them. I ran into the issue that im not 100% sure that my pattern is correct. Any comments that might make it easyer for me later on will be nice, but my problem is im not sure how to use the prototype correctly.

I use my module like this:

```
        var cm = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
            lineNumbers: true,
            matchBrackets: true,
            mode: "text/x-csharp"
        });
        var adapt = new $.codeMirrorSignalRAdapter(cm, $.connection.codeHub);
```

but in my adapter.prototype hubChange, the this.silent is undefined. I would like to think that the var adapter = function(cm,hub) is the constructor and i do not know how i access the properties, self.[cm,hub,silent] from the prototype functions.

```
(function ($, window) {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof ($) !== "function") {
        // no jQuery!
        throw new Error("CodeMirrorAdapter: jQuery not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before the SignalR.js file.");
    }
    if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
        throw new Error("CodeMirrorAdapter: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/hubs.");
    }

    var adapter = function (cm, hub) {
        var self = this;
        self.cm = cm;
        self.hub = hub;
        self.silent = false;

        cm.on("change", function (_, change) { self.onChange(change); });
        hub.client.Change = self.hubChange;

        return self;
    };

    adapter.fn = adapter.prototype = {
        init: function (cm, hub) {

        },
        onChange: function (change) {
            if (!this.silent) {
                this.hub.server.change(change)
                        .done(function () { })
                        .fail(function (ee) { alert(ee) });
            }
        },
        hubChange: function (change) {
            alert(this.silent);
            this.silent = true;
            this.cm.replaceRange(change.text[0], change.from);
            this.silent = false;
        },
    };


    $.codeMirrorSignalRAdapter = adapter;
}(window.jQuery, window));
```

Other than the problem with this keyword, does the module design look somewhat okay?

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` can be any of 5 possible options. Read this article on MDN for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

In your particular case, `hub.client.Change = self.hubChange;`, you are registering `hubChange` as the handler. The issue is when the handler is called, there is no code to ensure `this` has been set to the correct adapter object.

How do we ensure that?

```
hub.client.Change = function () { self.hubChange.apply(self, arguments);};
```

You can read more about `apply` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

What we have done is similar to what you did with the `cm.on("change")` binding.

**Thoughts on the code**

Your constructor function ends with a `return self;` That is not needed. When the function is called as a constructor, ie with the `new` keyword, it will implicitly return a new instance. When the function is called without the `new` keyword, it will return whatever the function is returning, which in this case will NOT be a new instance. It will be whatever `this` has been set to. Most likely it will return `window`. Suggestion, remove that line. That way if you accidentally call it without the new, you will get back undefined.

Comment: Thank you, i will take a moment to read up on it. The apply solves the problem.

Comment: @s093294, if my attempt answers your question, I would appreciate if you could mark it as the accepted answer. If not, please comment on what is left unanswered.